# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' For virtual Environment

Tags: python, django

The Pillow library is installed for my Python environment `my_proj` still it is throwing the Error PIL module is not there.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check your python actual path which you use currently I think in your system python is installed two or more times so your working python directory is different and pip has installed the package at another python directory.

I think python install with a default path like

===== In my case Python's defalt path is like this =====

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
```

===== In your case Python's defalt path is like this =====

```
C:\Users\<Your Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the problem has been solved. I don't know what the problem was, but after deleting the virtual environment and creating a new one, it has been resolved.

Comment: Please press up arrow for vote